# Send a new password - CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to set a new password to users when they forget the old one.
I have the code, it's working ( Creates a new random password, updates the database and sends it by email to the entered email ) however when I try to login with the new password it says invalid password ( Obviously the old one is incorrect as well )

My code is :

```
function forgot() {
if(!empty($this->data)) {
     $user = $this->User->findByEmail($this->data['User']['email']);
     $user_email = $this->data['User']['email'];
     if($user) {
       $user['User']['tmp_password'] = $this->User->createTempPassword(10);
       $user['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($user['User']['tmp_password']);
        if($this->User->save($user, false)) {
            $this->User->set('User.password', $user['User']['password'], array('User.email' => $user_email));       
            $this->User->save();
            $this->__sendPasswordEmail($user,$user['User']['tmp_password']);
            $this->Session->setFlash('An email has been sent with your new password.');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
       }
     } else {
       $this->Session->setFlash('No user was found with the submitted email address.');
     }
   }
}



 public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    // hash our password
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
    }

    // if we get a new password, hash it
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']) && !empty($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update'])) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password_update']);
    }

    // fallback to our parent
    return parent::beforeSave($options);
}


function createTempPassword() {
$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
$pass = array(); //remember to declare $pass as an array
$alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1; //put the length -1 in cache
for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
    $pass[] = $alphabet[$n];
}
return implode($pass); //turn the array into a string
}
```

I read a few similar questions and I've seen that password hashing might be a problem but I don't see where does that interacts in my code because I use the same hashing method. (You might ask why I used $this->User->set / Save - Well, I was just playing around try to figure out the issue, wasn't that. )

Password be like : BT9DPRsN - bcfbde69a31197d18589e81dd41af6dbc3c21557

Thank you.

Comment: you are hashing the password twice.

Comment: You mean in beforeSave function ?

Comment: and please share `createTempPassword()` for better understanding, but i guess it solved your problem

Comment: you do not need this line `$user['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($user['User']['tmp_password']);`

Comment: I added createTempPassword() . Ok, I'll try.

Comment: I wouldnt call it passwords, but tokens, as they should be a random one-use string of some sort, see http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/25/tools-plugin-part1-codekey/ And then you don't need any hashing etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment this line and it will work for you `$user['User']['password'] = $this->Auth->password($user['User']['tmp_password']);`

Reason behind this is because you have already hashed the password in cakephp callback function `beforeSave` whenever you try to save password field in the database it will hash it first and then save. Hoped it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have hashed password twice,
The first in beforeSave() of Controller and the second in beforeSave() of Model(AppModel or User)
You should use it once, (can clear statement return beforeSave() in recent Controller or only defined beforeSave() in AppModel).

http://rao5s.vn